# which is the stronger logic statement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have two logic statements as follows:

$\forall a \exists b \forall c \; Sport(a,b,c)$ (for all $a$ and $c$, there exists a sport $b$ which they share)

and

$\forall a \forall c \exists b \;Sport(a,b,c)$

Now I want to know whether the two statements are equivalent, weaker or stronger than each other. When I try and "convert" these to plain english, they seem to be conveying the same thing but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The first statement implies the second, but not vice versa. This means that the former is stronger than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the order of the quantifiers means with regard to the dependence of the subsequent variable on the earlier ones. Prop 1 reads " for every a there is a b such that for every c P(a,b,c)." Where Prop 2 reads "for every a and for every c there is a b." In the second statement b depends on a and b whereas in the first statement b only depends on a and then works for any c you choose.

Comment: Could you link me to any material which explains this in further detail? I would appreciate it.

Comment: sure. I'm thinking about the difference in math between convergence and uniform convergence of a sequence of functions. A sequence of functions converges pointwise if for every $\epsilon$ and for every x there is an N such that.... But converges uniformly if for every $\epsilon$ and for every x there is an N..... The difference in the latter case is that the N works for every x whereas in the former there is an N for every x (not necessarily the same). This is e

Comment: (cont) equivalent to the statement that in pointwise convergence N is a function of x whereas for uniform convergence a single N works for every single x.

Comment: I guess the idea is that switching the $\forall$ and the $\exists$ quantifiers sqitches the dependence of the earlier variables. consider the simple statements: 1. for every a there is a b and there is a b for every a. in the latter case the b may depend on the choice of a in the relevant universe of discourse.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that the first statement in my original example is stronger? Because it only depends on $a$ and works for any c?

Comment: Yes. the first implies the second. Can you prove this?

Comment: How do I prove it?

Comment: Show that the first implies the second. Therefore showing that it is a stronger statement.

Comment: by "the second" do you mean the second statement? I don't even know where to start with the proof though..

Comment: If you think about it for a second, the same b works for all c in the first statement. so you automatically have the second. whereas in the second statement, different b's work for different c's, so you do not necessarily have that "there exists a b for all c"

Comment: So I don't necessarily need to follow a formal set of steps to prove this? I can just say that the first statement works for all c whereas the second statement has different b's for different c's?

Comment: just depends on how comfortable you feel with that. Try to work out the formal proof with this intuition if you feel uncomfortable with that type of response. But I don't see how that type of exercise is any more illuminating.

Comment: Would I need to build upon the points that you have made? It looks pretty convincing to me